# Rotating a cube about an axis through opposite vertices

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

I have a cube made using CSS transforms that I'm trying to animate rotating about an axis going through 2 opposite vertices.

**What I have:**

Initial cube:

```
   /* Animation start */
   rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
   /* Animation end */
   rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJnXZ.gif]

Rotated cube:

```
   /* Animation start */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
   /* Animation end */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/csYFP.gif]

Rotating X:

```
   /* Animation start */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
   /* Animation end */
   rotateX(315deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4ZVh.gif]

Rotating Y:

```
   /* Animation start */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
   /* Animation end */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(405deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W40DN.gif]

Rotating Z:

```
   /* Animation start */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
   /* Animation end */
   rotateX(-45deg) rotateY(45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RMWm.gif]

**What I want:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQN3Y.gif]

I'm not a programmer or a mathematician, and I've tried looking this up on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) and through past answers, but both get into some heavy matrix-transformation stuff and technical jargon  that goes over my head. I'm just trying to figure out the right numbers to plug in for the X, Y, and Z axes to achieve a "sideways" rotation.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**: I just noticed this, but I think CSS3's `rotateX` isn't behaving the way it should. Both `rotateY` and `rotateZ` act relative to the object - using its axes for rotations even when those axes have been rotated - but `rotateX` seems to always rotate relative to the viewport, no matter how much I try to stop it from doing that! This is evident even in the above pictures - `rotateY` and `rotateZ` both rotate the cube along one of its own axes, but `rotateX` instead rotates the whole cube along the viewport's X axis.  I *think* this might be an implementation bug; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure. Have you tried `rotate3d(x,y,z,???deg)` with $x = y = z = 1$. Up to my understanding, it is supposed to rotate  around the axis in the direction $(x,y,z)$ for ??? degree. Not sure about its support across browsers.

Comment: Achille, I tried that (I used `rotate3d(1,1,1,0deg)` through `360deg` but it didn't result in the cube being rotated as pictured. I think `rotate3d` is using the same reference frame as `rotateX`, `rotateY`, and `rotateZ` so it doesn't help - I still need to give it the correct (unknown) values to rotate correctly.

Comment: On firefox 28, after I set the `transform-origin` properly. following `@keyframes` specification allow me to generate a rotating cube with one of its diagonal always pointing upwards as in your last picture.
$$\bbox[background:#eeeeee]{\small\begin{align}
& \verb/@keyframes rotation2 {/\\
& \verb/    from { transform: rotateY(0deg) rotateX(54.735deg) rotateY(45deg);   }/\\
& \verb/      to { transform: rotateY(360deg) rotateX(54.735deg) rotateY(45deg); }/\\
& \verb/}/
\end{align}}
$$
Please note that you can stack multiple rotation along same direction in a single transform directive.